# How to add or remove cases based on condition?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame with the following structure:

```
   index  serial pnum grp Start_End
   168  11090618    1   12  t0900_0915, t1245_1300
   168  11090618    2   14  t0900_0915, t1445_1500
   168  11090618    3   NA  
   189  11110817    1   16  t1115_1130, t1200_1215
   189  11110817    1   18  t1930_1945, t2230_2245
   2769 17090608    1   NA  
   2769 17090608    2   NA  
   2770 17090612    1   NA  
   2770 17090612    2   NA  
   2770 17090612    3   NA
```

Some brief descriptions of variables

`index:` - variable used to group the cases based on the serial number (eg. serial and index measure the same things)

`serial:` describes the case number

`pnum:` describes the measurement at person level;

Start_End@ the start and end of the measurement

How can I keep all the cases at the person level (eh. serial and pnum) if one person took a measurement (has filled in the Start_End column)

Eg.In the above case pnum 1 and pnum 2 recorded measurement so I would like to keep it

```
       index  serial pnum grp Start_End
       168  11090618    1   12  t0900_0915, t1245_1300
       168  11090618    2   14  t0900_0915, t1445_1500
       168  11090618    3   NA
```

...but below there is no measurement record for the any of the case I would like to remove

```
   index  serial pnum grp Start_End
   2770 17090612    1   NA  
   2770 17090612    2   NA  
   2770 17090612    3   NA

   df <-structure(list(index = structure(c(168, 168, 168, 189, 189, 189, 
    189, 458, 458, 458, 673, 673, 673, 673, 733, 733, 733, 1034, 
    1034, 1034, 1065, 1065, 1065, 1065, 1065, 1075, 1075, 1075, 1075, 
    1225, 1225, 1225, 1235, 1235, 1235, 1235, 1377, 1377, 1377, 1477, 
    1477, 1477, 1477, 1662, 1662, 1662, 1662, 1789, 1789, 1789, 1789, 
    1891, 1891, 1891, 1891, 1961, 1961, 1961, 2093, 2093, 2093, 2161, 
    2161, 2161, 2202, 2202, 2202, 2202, 2503, 2503, 2503, 2503, 2598, 
    2598, 2598, 2598, 2614, 2614, 2614, 2614, 2614, 2614, 2643, 2643, 
    2643, 2643, 2643, 2643, 2768, 2769, 2769, 2770, 2770, 2770, 2771, 
    2772, 2773, 2773, 2773, 2773), label = "group(serial)", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
        serial = structure(c(11090618, 11090618, 11090618, 11110817, 
        11110817, 11110817, 11110817, 11310303, 11310303, 11310303, 
        12150906, 12150906, 12150906, 12150906, 12190110, 12190110, 
        12190110, 13101102, 13101102, 13101102, 13140416, 13140416, 
        13140416, 13140416, 13140416, 13150903, 13150903, 13150903, 
        13150903, 13260115, 13260115, 13260115, 13271014, 13271014, 
        13271014, 13271014, 14080604, 14080604, 14080604, 14140715, 
        14140715, 14140715, 14140715, 14290913, 14290913, 14290913, 
        14290913, 15070719, 15070719, 15070719, 15070719, 15131017, 
        15131017, 15131017, 15131017, 15180803, 15180803, 15180803, 
        15260108, 15260108, 15260108, 15310317, 15310317, 15310317, 
        16020619, 16020619, 16020619, 16020619, 16230313, 16230313, 
        16230313, 16230313, 16291210, 16291210, 16291210, 16291210, 
        16310311, 16310311, 16310311, 16310311, 16310311, 16310311, 
        17020216, 17020216, 17020216, 17020216, 17020216, 17020216, 
        17090602, 17090608, 17090608, 17090612, 17090612, 17090612, 
        17101101, 17101106, 17101107, 17101107, 17101107, 17101107
        ), label = "serial", format.stata = "%9.0f"), pnum = structure(c(1, 
        2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
        1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
        1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
        1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 
        1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 
        1, 2, 3, 4), label = "pnum", format.stata = "%9.0g"), grp = structure(c(12, 
        14, NA, 16, 18, NA, NA, 50, 48, NA, NA, 100, 102, NA, 110, 
        NA, NA, 150, NA, NA, 156, 154, 152, NA, NA, 160, 158, NA, 
        NA, 162, 164, NA, 168, 166, NA, NA, NA, 198, NA, NA, 224, 
        222, NA, NA, 234, 236, NA, NA, 258, 256, NA, 260, 264, 262, 
        NA, 290, NA, NA, 320, 322, NA, 332, NA, NA, NA, 350, 352, 
        NA, 412, 410, NA, NA, 430, 426, 428, NA, 446, 448, 444, 452, 
        450, NA, 464, 468, 466, 472, 470, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = "grp", format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
        Start_End = structure(c("t0900_0915, t1245_1300", "t0900_0915, t1445_1500", 
        "", "t1115_1130, t1200_1215", "t1930_1945, t2230_2245", "", 
        "", "t1015_1030, t1245_1300", "t0830_0845, t2045_2100", "", 
        "", "t0630_0645, t1045_1100", "t1315_1330, t1845_1900", "", 
        "t0800_0815, t1845_1900", "", "", "t0800_0815, t1745_1800", 
        "", "", "t1845_1900, t2215_2230", "t1600_1615, t1745_1800", 
        "t0830_0845, t1445_1500", "", "", "t1300_1315, t1630_1645", 
        "t0830_0845, t1215_1230", "", "", "t0700_0715, t1745_1800", 
        "t0800_0815, t1645_1700", "", "t1900_1915, t2015_2030", "t1200_1215, t1515_1530", 
        "", "", "", "t0630_0645, t1445_1500", "", "", "t1500_1515, t1845_1900", 
        "t0900_0915, t1345_1400", "", "", "t0930_0945, t1345_1400", 
        "t1445_1500, t1815_1830", "", "", "t0130_0145, t0200_0215", 
        "t0800_0815, t1715_1730", "", "t0900_0915, t1500_1515", "t1130_1145, t1400_1415", 
        "t0730_0745, t1045_1100", "", "t0830_0845, t1715_1730", "", 
        "", "t1100_1115, t1745_1800", "t0900_0915, t1745_1800", "", 
        "t0700_0715, t1845_1900", "", "", "", "t0930_0945, t1645_1700", 
        "t1830_1845, t1845_1900", "", "t1330_1345, t1745_1800", "t0900_0915, t1245_1300", 
        "", "", "t1330_1345, t1545_1600", "t0900_0915, t1345_1400", 
        "t1430_1445, t1745_1800", "", "t1315_1330, t1445_1500", "t1515_1530, t1645_1700", 
        "t0800_0815, t1245_1300", "t1330_1345, t1845_1900", "t0800_0815, t1245_1300", 
        "", "t0900_0915, t1145_1200", "t2000_2015, t2145_2200", "t1230_1245, t1745_1800", 
        "t1930_1945, t2315_2330", "t0900_0915, t1830_1845", "", "", 
        "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), label = "Start_End", format.stata = "%22s")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It looks like a filter `df[!is.na(df$grp),]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'index', 'serial', `filter` the groups where there is `any` non-NA element in 'grp'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(index, serial) %>%
    filter(any(!is.na(grp)))
```

---

Or using `sum` with `complete.cases`

```
df %>%
     group_by(index, serial) %>% 
     filter(sum(complete.cases(grp)) > 0)
```

Comment: thank you but for example  in the case 11090618  I would like al cases even though grp is NA

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options using base R and `data.table` :

```
subset(df, ave(Start_End != '', index, serial, FUN = any))
# A tibble: 88 x 5
#   index   serial  pnum   grp Start_End               
#   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                   
# 1   168 11090618     1    12 "t0900_0915, t1245_1300"
# 2   168 11090618     2    14 "t0900_0915, t1445_1500"
# 3   168 11090618     3    NA ""                      
# 4   189 11110817     1    16 "t1115_1130, t1200_1215"
# 5   189 11110817     1    18 "t1930_1945, t2230_2245"
# 6   189 11110817     2    NA ""                      
# 7   189 11110817     3    NA ""                      
# 8   458 11310303     1    50 "t1015_1030, t1245_1300"
# 9   458 11310303     2    48 "t0830_0845, t2045_2100"
#10   458 11310303     3    NA ""                      
# … with 78 more rows
```

Using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[any(Start_End != '')], .(index, serial)]
```